# How to force the update of a property in python?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, bezier-curves

I'm writing a function that should return the frame when a field reaches a certain value in the property window.

To be more specific here the function:

```
def getFrameFromPercentagePosition(context, pCurveObject, pPercentagePosition):
    context.scene.frame_current = 1
    while pCurveObject.data.bevel_factor_end < pPercentagePosition:
        context.scene.update()
        context.scene.frame_current += 1
    return context.scene.frame_current
```

The field bevel_factor_end is animated between 0 and 1 and I want to know the frame when its value reaches the `pPercentagePosition` value.

But, after some debugging, I've found out that `pCurveObject.data.bevel_factor_end` is always 1.0 in this script. However, when I do manually in the interactive console by asking the bevel_factor_end of the active object, it gives me the right value.

How can I make sure that a got the correct value for this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using python to alter the current frame you should use [`scene.frame_set(f)`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set) which will update the scene so you can see animated values as they are at that frame.

A possible logic error in your code - you mention the value is animated between 0 and 1, if frame 1 is keyed to 0.0 then frame 1 will always return as being less than the tested value. You may want to consider a range that is acceptable to matching the value.

```
if val > (target - 0.1) and val < (target + 0.1):
    return frame
```

You should also find [`fcurve.evaluate(f)`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.evaluate) to be an easier and possibly faster solution as you don't need to update the scene to get the curve value.

```
def getFrameFromPercentagePosition(context, pCurveObject, pPercentagePosition):
    scn = context.scene
    fcurve = pCurveObject.data.animation_data.action.fcurves.find('bevel_factor_end')
    variance = 0.05
    for f in range(scn.frame_start, scn.frame_end):
        val = fcurve.evaluate(f)
        if val > (pPercentagePosition - variance) and val < (pPercentagePosition + variance):
            return f
```

Comment: It works like a charm with scene.frame_set(). Thanks a lot, that's perfect ! And you're right, it is much faster and logical to evaluate the F-Curve directly, I'll do it that way. Thanks again ! :)