# Get the transform matrix for each frame

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, transform-orientation

[image: path following camera]

I'm new to scripting inside blender (two days). I have a camera folowing a path (a circle).

I have written the following code to get the location and rotation for each frame and write it to a file:

```
import bpy

transformMetrix=open('C:\\Users\\sunimalm\\Desktop\\transformMetrix.txt','w')


for f in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start,bpy.context.scene.frame_end):
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        transformMetrix.write('\n'+obj.name+'\n')
        transformMetrix.write('\n'+ str(f)+'\n')
        transformMetrix.write('Location : ' + str(obj.location.x) +' '+ str(obj.location.y) +' '+ str(obj.location.z) +'\n')
        transformMetrix.write('rotation : ' + str(obj.rotation_euler.x) +' '+str(obj.rotation_euler.y) +' '+str(obj.rotation_euler.z)+'\n')
        transformMetrix.write('scale : ' + str(int(obj.scale.x)) +' '+str(int(obj.scale.y))+' '+str(int(obj.scale.z)) +'\n')

transformMetrix.close()
```

When I play and run the script I only get the same rotation and location matrix for every frame.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Then I tried to put above code inside a function and append it to a handler, but I still get the same output:

```
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(function)
```

Comment: Looks like to me that you just iterate through the frames but don't ask where the object is in a certain frame, just where the object is (that will be frame 0 or 1 w/e)

Comment: Get the fcurves for the animation and use [`fcurve.evaluate()`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42529/935) to get the values at a given frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the frame in your for-loop via [`Scene.frame_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set):

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
```

By the way, I would not use `obj.location`, `rotation_euler` etc. because they do not contain the final location, rotation and so on.
For example, parent your camera to an object, then rotate the object - the `camera.rotation_euler` will not change.

You should use [`obj.matrix_world`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=matrix_world#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world) instead (if you need it separated, decompose this matrix with [to_location, to_euler etc.](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_euler))

Comment: Note too the [decompose](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.decompose) method `loc, rot, scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Adding `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)` for the initial code  didn't gave me the expected output. it was same as the result I posted. I think this is because of the issue mentioned here right? but setting the frame  `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)` and taking the transform metrix with  `obj.matrix_world` worked.