# How can I animate matrix transforms like rotation or scaling?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, transforms, mathematics

Can transform matrix be animated with keyframes or do I have to do this manually? e.g. How could I animate this rotation? I know how to set keyframes on rotation, but i need/want to use transforms.

```
R = Matrix.Rotation(pi / 2, 4, 'X')
    
for ob in outer_collectionBig.all_objects:  
    ob.data.transform(R)
```

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44760/rotate-objects-around-their-origin-along-a-global-axis-scripted-without-bpy-op/44783#44783 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/116505/31447

Comment: @Brockmann : i want to animate the transformation...the links are about matrices...aren't they?